# Unable to add PSSnapin for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell getting error related to unable to cast object

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

While adding the PSSnapin for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell using below command

```
Add-PSSnapin 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell'
```

getting this error

> Add-PSSnapin : Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell because of the following error:
>   Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn' to
>   type'System.Management.Automation.CustomPSSnapIn'.

Running this command `Get-PSSnapin -Registered | fl *` I am getting a proper result for installed **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell**

```
Name                        : Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
IsDefault                   : False
ApplicationBase             : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools
AssemblyName                : Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
ModuleName                  : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll
PSVersion                   : 5.1
Version                     : 14.0.0.0
Types                       : {}
Formats                     : {}
Description                 : This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets.
Vendor                      : Microsoft Corporation
LogPipelineExecutionDetails : False
```

- Verified while installing the Power Tools, I selected the option to install PowerShell Cmdlets
- Also, I have verified the **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll** exist and it has a proper registry entry at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell`.
- Tried repairing and reinstalling the TFS15 Power Tools, but nothing helped.
- I am using windows 10 version 1809(OS build: 17763.55).

PowerShell 5.1

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have fully installed the [TFS Powertools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2013Power).

By default it doesn’t install the **PowerShell CmdLets**. If it is, just install it and then the issue will be gone.

Another possibility is that the PowerShell Snap-in is stored in the inconsistent registry with the OS version (32bit/64bit).

> PowerTools installer is 32bit, on 64bit machine, it will write to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns,
>   but not to 
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns.

Reference this similar thread for details: [TFS Power Tools 2008 Powershell Snapin won’t run in on 64-bit in Windows 2008 R2?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a116799a-0476-4c42-aa3e-45d8ba23739e/tfs-power-tools-2008-powershell-snapin-won8217t-run-in-on-64bit-in-windows-2008-r2?forum=tfspowertools)

Comment: I have Verified that while installing the Power Tools, I selected the option to install PowerShell Cmdlets. Also, I checked in other machines where it works fine the reg-entry is at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns`

Comment: @vrnithinkumar, sounds like you run into a known issue with `CustomPSSnapIn` and `SPCmdletSnapIn` types cast. I suggest you to try uninstall `Microsoft Windows Management Framework 3.0 (KB2506143)` and install it again.

Comment: I did not find an installer for windows 10.
I am using windows 10 version 1809(OS build: 17763.55).

Comment: @vrnithinkumar, try to reinstall `Windows Management Framework 4.0` then.

Comment: I could not find a proper installer for WMF4.0 which did not throw an unsupported error.